# mongo db aggregate returns empty string from projection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following structure in the mongo db (conversations collection):

Example of the content:

```
[
   {
  "channel_names" :
  [
    {
      "name" : "users_58908cf4-cfdf-499b-83f9-c7a0aa36fae0"
    },
    {
      "name" : "chats_55e6dd6776ed6652f40af20c",
      "type" : "events"
    }
  ],
  "messages":[{"text":"a"},{"text":"b"},{"text":"c"}]
}
]
```

I would like to aggregate the data and return data as follow e.g.:

```
[{'id' - '55e6dd6776ed6652f40af20c' , 'message_count' : 3 }]
```

**sorted by message_count descending**

I have the following code:

```
{ $project : { _id : false , id : { '$cond' : [ { '$eq' : [ '$channel_names.type' , 'events' ] } , '$channel_names.name' , '' ] } , message_count : { $size : { '$ifNull' : [ '$messages' , [] ] } } } }

{ $sort : { messages : -1 } }
```

**db.collection.aggregate(...)**

my problem is that `$channel_names.name` always returns empty string

example of my output:

```
[
  {
    "id": "",
    "message_count": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "",
    "message_count": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "",
    "message_count": 5
  },
  {
    "id": "",
    "message_count": 2
  }
]
```

because `$channel_names.name` is mapped to id and `$channel_names.name` returns empty string - id is always an empty string

Answer (score 1):

In the document, channel_names is an array, hence you have to do unwind first. Please try following pipeline.

```
pipeline = [
  {
    $unwind: '$channel_names'
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: false,
      id: '$channel_names.name',
      message_count: {$size: '$messages'}
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      message_count: -1
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi , first of all it finally works !!! second now i get the chats_1231231231243124 , but i need only the numbers after the underscore

Comment: Use $substr in projection or in your client program.

Comment: I know , but I need your help with the syntax inside the $cond that i wrote on the top , i tried a few variations but they all failed , i would appreciate if you could add the substr into my $project part

Comment: @Stephan does the prefix is always 6 characters like users_, chats_ ?

Comment: yes - is there any way to split the string and take the right side ?
or maybe just substr from the position of the underscore

Comment: @Stephen - In above project operation replace  id: '$channel_names.name', with id: {$substr: ['$channel_names.name',6, -1]}